# Azure Function to Read & Write to Blob using HTTP Trigger

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

Let me preface with saying I am by no means a C# developer, so I apologize for the novice questions and subsequent responses.

I am trying to write an Azure Function that once invoked with an HTTP trigger, will go to a blob, read the data, transform the data, and then write to another blob storage. Ignoring the transformation layer, I am simply trying to read from blob and upload to a separate blob. Below is the code I currently have:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static void Run(HttpRequest req, Stream inputBlob, Stream outputBlob, ILogger log)
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inputBlob);
    string  text = reader.ReadToEnd();
    await outputBlob.UploadTextAsync(text)
}
```

Here are my bindings:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    },
    {
      "name": "inputBlob",
      "direction": "in",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "path/to/file",
      "connection": "*********_STORAGE"
    },
    {
      "name": "outputBlob",
      "direction": "out",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "path/to/file",
      "connection": "*********_STORAGE"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I test it in the Azure Function UI, I get a status of 500 - Internal Server Error. If I test it in the classic viewer, the Logs gives me the response of "This request is not authorized to perform this operation." I am using the Azure UI to develop as the VSCode Azure Function Core Tools I can't setup on my machine.

Can somebody please give some input/pointers as to where I'm going wrong? Any code snippets/examples would be greatly appreciated, but I've pretty much scoured all of StackOverflow and haven't been able to successfully run any of the snippets I've found.

Comment: Is the connection the connection string? The second error that you get from classic sounds like you are not using the correct connection string so you are not authenticating.

Comment: have you tried to test it locally, adding some breakpoints to find out what exact statement is raising it? 
If not mistaken, I remember facing a similar error when trying to save or load a file using relative paths when running on the azure environment. You have no permission to mess up with the cloud file system, except on the directory which your function is running.

Comment: Hi Jacob, may I know if your problem was solved ? If still have problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, I test it in my side with your code. Please refer to the solution below:

**1.** It doesn't exist a method `UploadTextAsync()` in `Stream outputBlob`. So please use the code below to write the text from `inputBlob` to `outputBlob`.

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
await outputBlob.WriteAsync(bytes);
```

Also provide all of my function code below for your reference:

[image]

**2.** Apart from edit your function code, please also check if the binding of your function.json same to mine (the `test` in `path` is the container name in storage).

[image]

And the `storageCon` is the name of the value(connection string) which should be added in application settings. **We can't hardcode the connection string in function.json**.

[image]

**3.** Run the function, it will read the inputBlob file and write it to outputBlob file.

Hope it helps~